# Ajax for stringifying values from rest controller in HTML file does not get executed

Tags: html, ajax

I am using an ajax script to stringify the values from a controller of an application which is spring rest web service application..problem is when the values in html in form i click a button, this script should work but doesn't get executed..can someone help me what's wrong in the script, is a load problem or something else, and what is the right way of making it executable???

**Ajax Script**

```
    load$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var url = 'http://localhost:8080/xxx/authenticate';
        var jsondata = JSON.stringify({
            username: $('#inputEmail').val(),
            password: $('#inputPassword').val()
        });
        postdata(url, jsondata, 1);
    });

    $('#register-dev').click(function () {
        var url = 'http://localhost:8080/xxx/register';
        alert(url);

        var jsondata = JSON.stringify({
            roleTb: {
                roleId: parseInt($('#role').val())
            },
            firstName: $('#firstname').val(),
            lastName: $('#lastname').val(),
            emailId: $('#email').val(),
            username: $('#username').val(),
            password: $('#password').val()
        });
        postdata(url, jsondata, 2);
    });

    function postdata(url, jsondata, formId) {
        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: jsondata
        });

        request.done(function (msg) {
            if (formId == 1) {
                if (msg.errorcode == 200 && msg.obj == true) {
                    alert("Authentication Successful");
                } else {
                    alert("Authentication failed");
                }
            }

            if (formId == 2) {
                if (msg.errorcode == 200) {
                    alert("Registration Successful Your Access Id is " + msg.obj);
                } else {
                    alert("Registration failed");
                }
            }
        });
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        });
    }
});
```

**HTML FORM**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- Title and other stuffs -->
        <title>xxxxxx Login</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ajax-handler.js"></script>
        <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <!-- Favicon -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Form area -->
        <div class="admin-form">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <!-- Widget starts -->
                        <div class="widget worange">
                            <!-- Widget head -->
                            <div class="widget-head"> <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login</div>
                            <div class="widget-content">
                                <div class="padd">
                                    <!-- Login form -->
                                    <form class="form-horizontal">
                                        <!-- Email -->
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-lg-3" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Password -->
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-lg-3" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Remember me checkbox and sign in button -->
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
                                            <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Sign in</button>
                                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Reset</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="widget-foot">Not Registred? <a href="register.html">Register here</a>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should prevent the default hard form submit if you wish to use asynchronous submission. Otherwise form gets refreshed

   ```
   $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
   ```
2. check whether you really need to *stringify* the data. Normally, in most cases it's just enough to pass it as an object to [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), unless the server really needs it as JSON string. jQuery internally does the necessary conversion. (serializes to query string) if it's an object or array.

   ```
   var jsondata = {
       username: $('#inputEmail').val(),
       password: $('#inputPassword').val()
   };
   ```

Comment: I m creating rest web services where requires to stringify the values in jason, today my luck has a fight with me, the script is still not working..when clicking on the button, the values don't submit and alerts anything...

Comment: code-jaff - can you suggest me something more point to point to get out of  this problem. your suggestion was valuable but that's not clicking here, can you help me on further on this??

Comment: `load` at the top is a typo? And, have you tried `e.preventDefaut()`?

Comment: Please answer my first question,  and have you tried to inspect the developer tool's console? It'll show you the exact errors possibly.

Comment: However my problem still remains unsolved, but still would check your answer right, as its being useful and valuable..thanx